# jQuery equivalent of body onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it allowed to use `<body onLoad="myfunc()">` along with jQuery's `document.ready()` handlers?
I can't find a way to achieve the same functionality of the `<body onLoad>` with jQuery.

An example of a use case would be a facebook application. An Iframe facebook app requires the use of the `FB.Canvas.setSize` function which resize the iframe.

I would need to fire it up only when all elements on the page are finished loading.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`$(window).load(myfunc)` is what you're looking for. If you're working with the load event of an iframe, you can replace `window` with the iframe element/selector.

Comment: In case I create the iFrame dynamically later on, it seems like it is not possible to use .live() and load.. is there any solution for that?

Comment: After creating the iframe (e.g. `var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');`), you can pass it a load event callback with `$(iframe).load(myfunc);`. I would recommend doing this before attaching it to the DOM and/or setting its `src` attribute.

Comment: I tried using both $(window).load(FB.Canvas.setSize()) and jQuery(document).loadFB.Canvas.setSize()) . However, none of them resize the window as opposed to using <body onload="FB.Canvas.setSize()"> which does the job.  It seems like they act differently

Comment: Neither of those would work. You want something like this: `$(iframe).load(function() { FB.Canvas.setSize(); });` If this still doesn't work, please edit your original question and provide more code/context.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have control over the iFrame creation. It is made by facebook (using XFBML). Therefore, I can not pass it a load event callback.

Comment: Understood. You can attach the load event callback to the window before creating the iframe: `$(window).load(function() { FB.Canvas.setSize(); }); // then create iframe`

Comment: Is it possible to use replace the window with `functionExample`? So `functionNewExample` runs if `functionExample` has been completed?

Answer (score 8):

This works as well:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // ..
    myfunc();
    // ..
});
```

Comment: How does this improve the accepted answer? There's much less verbose methods to do this....

Answer (score 7):

`.load(),` `.unload()` or `.error()` are deprecated since jQuery 1.8.
Lookup for these aliases in your code and replace them with the .on() method instead

```
$(window).on('load', function(){...})
```

Comment: Link to deprecated [load event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: Link to JQuery 3.0+ AJAX short-hand [method called load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/); readers should be aware of the difference when looking at their code (and resulting errors).

Answer (score 5):

From the jQuery API on the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

> The .ready() method is generally
>   incompatible with the <body onload="">
>   attribute. If load must be used,
>   either do not use .ready() or use
>   jQuery's .load() method to attach load
>   event handlers to the window or to
>   more specific items, like images.

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread updating some old code that had `<body onload="someFunc()">` so to give an updated answer:

Don't use `load()`. While `$(document).ready(function(){...});` should work (depending on your use case) you actually want: `$(window).on('load', function(){...});` to more closely mimic `<body onload="...">`

[Some threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38871753/uncaught-typeerror-a-indexof-is-not-a-function-error-when-opening-new-foundat) suggest this has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8 (as well as `.unload()` and `.error()`) and should be replaced with proper `.on()` implementations. I've confirmed that using `load()` on 3.3.1 results in an error, namely: `indexOf is not a function` in jquery.min.js

[Documentation For jQuery's `on`Event Handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I thought `$(window).on('load', function () {...})` was the same thing as `$(window).load(function() {...})`. Are they not?

Comment: Well they function similarly, however load() & on() are indeed two different & unique functions. I was just cautioning that I had found some sources stating the 'load'/'unload' were being phased out in favor of the more flexible 'on' function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `load()`:

```
jQuery(document).load(myfunc)
```

Comment: I don't think you want to be passing the return value of `myfunc` to the `load` event ;)

Comment: Please see my last comment to Kevin's answer