# What's the difference between using onload in the DOM and .load() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example:

```
<iframe onload="functionName('id-name', 'http://domain.com');"/>
```

versus

```
$('#id-name').load(functionName('id-name', "http://domain.com');
```

(Actually... is my jQuery right?)

UPDATE: Thanks, all, for the responses. I'm using:

```
$('#id-name').load(function() {
    functionName('id-name', 'http://domain.com');
});
```

ETA: "body" was supposed to be an iframe (oops), so am not using window.load.

Comment: No, your jQuery should be `$(function () { functionName('id-name', "http://domain.com") });`

Comment: The jquery should be `.load(function() {functionName(...);});`.

Comment: Read about the jquery load function here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: isn't it better being `$(window).load(functionName)` ?

Comment: @dhsto That's the wrong `load()` function. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ is the one he's asking about.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I posted to the wrong load function. Always good to do a bit more reading though :)

Comment: well, for one, `$('#id-name').load(` will only do anything if it's targeting an iframe or image that hasn't already loaded. If used properly though, it would work exactly the same. `$(window).load(thefunction)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the syntax of your jQuery is wrong. The jQuery that's analogous would be:

```
$('#id-name').load(function() {
    functionName('id-name', "http://domain.com');
});
```

To bind an event handler, you have to supply a function, you were actually calling the function at the binding time.

However, this is not equivalent for a few reasons.

First, you're binding the handler to the `#id-name` element, not the body (unles you also did `<body id="id-name">`. So it wouldn't run when the body is loaded, but only when that specific element is loaded. In general, per-element load handlers are only useful for elements that have separate sources that get loaded asynchronously (e.g. images and iframes); they allow you to detect and take action when those elements are filled in. This is particular useful if you're changing the source dynamically.

Second, ssuming your jQuery code is in the `$(document).ready(...)` handler, as most jQuery code is, it doesn't run until after the DOM is fully loaded. By that time, the body's `onload` event has already been triggered. Any handlers added at this time will not run for elements that were already loaded. I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wNYjB/3/) that demonstrates this:

```
<body onload="alert('inline body onload');">
    <div id="foo"></div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#foo").load(function () {
        alert("foo onload");
    });

    $("body").load(function () {
        alert("jquery body onload");
    });
});
```

Only the `inline body onload` alert fires.

However, if you just want a jQuery equivalent to putting a function call in the `<body onload="">` attribute, the `$(document).ready()` handler is considered analogous. See [jQuery equivalent of body onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638296/jquery-equivalent-of-body-onload), the first question in the **Related** sidebar.

However, as Gloserio's answer says, `$(window).load(...)` does work, despite the timing (it's recognized specially, similar to `$(document).ready()`). This modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wNYjB/4/) demonstrates it.

Comment: You are right about jQuery checking specifically for it. It treats `$(document).ready`, `$(document).load` and `$(window).load` all that way (the callback fires immediately, but still asynchronously), if the even has already occured.

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks. I knew that `ready()` was special -- even more so, it ignores the element that it's bound to.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! Do you understand why the alert fired twice in this case? (JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wNYjB/8/)

Comment: (Re: "Any handlers added at this time will not run for elements that were already loaded.")

Comment: Iframes are loaded asynchronously, I don't think the document ready handler waits for them to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function () {
              functionName('id-name', "http://domain.com');
            });
```

Seems to be a fair enough equivalent of body's `load` event.

---

**Related** :

- [load event in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)
- SOF has answered all : [jQuery equivalent of body onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638296/jquery-equivalent-of-body-onload)

Answer (score -2):

`onload` is a DOM event that is triggered when the page begins to load.

`.load()` is a shortcut to an AJAX call using jQuery.

They really have nothing in common...other than having "load" in their names.

Comment: When the first argument to `.load()` is a function, it binds the `onload` event. See http://api.jquery.com/load-event/.