# Proper way to add onload function to body using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On one of my previous pages I use

```
 <script src="/js/wireEvent.js"></script> 
<body onload="wireEvent();" >
```

Basically, wireEvent() displays an image on top of the page whenever the mouse goes out of the browser.
However, now I cannot add this function directly to the body of my page, so what is the proper way to add it? Will it be right if I add

```
<script>
 window.onload = wireEvent;
</script>
```

or I enclose the whole function in

```
 $( document ).ready
```

and only include the function's file to my html?

Comment: Enclosing the function in `ready()` is not required. Don't use inline handlers, use `window.onload = wireEvent;` in `<script>`

Comment: `$( document ).ready` is a jquery implementation, `window.load` is native javascript implementation and  `body onload` is inline event handler. So what is the requirement?

Comment: Finally I used <script>window.onload = wireEvent;</script>, I was not sure what is the difference and what are the best practices.Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery equivalent of body onLoad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638296/jquery-equivalent-of-body-onload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below executes only after all your images load completely. So you can try this:

```
$(document).on('load', function(){
   wireEvent();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
$(function(){ 
//jQuery code here 
});
```